# When would you use different primes for the decomposition of primes for integers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For example, let's say you had $a$ and $b$ which are integers and $(a, b) = d$.

Would you write the decompositions for $a$, $b$, and $d$ in terms of the same primes since they have some in common? Or would you first write it for $d$ and then express $a$ and $b$ as multiples of $d$ times some constants, one for $a$ and another for $b$? Just a simple explanation would suffice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It sounds like I would be much more concerned about the relation of $a$ and $b$ to $d$. Let's say $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes coprime to $d$ and $a = pd$ and $b = qd$. I wouldn't care too much about what $d$ is as long as $d \neq 0$. But I'm just running my mouth on a hypothetical with hardly any context.

Comment: No prime factorization is required when using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most mathematical writing, this is a matter of context. If $a=20$ and $b=70$, then we could write:
$$a=10\cdot2, \quad b=10\cdot7,$$
or
$$a=2^2\cdot5, \quad b=2\cdot5\cdot7,$$
or
$$a=2d, \quad b=7d, \quad \text{where }d=2\cdot5,$$
or simply
$$a=20, \quad b=70.$$
It depends on what we're trying to highlight by factoring in the first place, so there's no one "right answer" in general.